# How to connect a branch to a work item via DevOps CLI or API

Tags: git, azure-devops

I want to be able to connect an existing branch in a git repo to a work item in Azure DevOps, via CLI or API or any way that isn't the UI (I do that all day long in the UI and want to make a script instead). I found this open issue in GitHub:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/issues/153

My take-away from this is that this feature is not implemented in the extension. Instead, I turned to the REST API. But I can't figure out how to do what I want. Creating a new branch and connect it in the same operation would be ok as well, but preferably I want to just connect an existing branch.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, sorry, haven't had the time to get back to this until today. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to connect an existing branch in a git repo to a work item in Azure DevOps.

You could use the Rest API: [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to link the work item with the existing Branch.

Here is the Example:

Request URL:

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.1
```

Request Body:

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/relations/-",
    "value": {
      "rel": "ArtifactLink",
      "url": "vstfs:///Git/Ref/{ProjectID}/{RepoId}/GB{BranchName}",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Branch",
        "comment": "test link branch"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

To Get the Project ID, you could use this Rest API: [Projects - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

**Note:** use Project Name to replace Project ID in the URL

To Get the Repo ID, you could use this Rest API: [Repositories - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1)

**Note:** use Repo Name to replace Repo ID in the URL.

You can also use powershell to combine these three rest apis.

Here is an example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$branchname = "Branch Name"

$url1="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/_apis/projects/{Project Name}?api-version=6.0" #url to get Projectid

$url2 ="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/{Project Name}/_apis/git/repositories/{Repo Name}?api-version=4.1" #url to get Repoid

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/{Project Name}/_apis/wit/workitems/{WorkItem ID}?api-version=5.1" #url to update workitem

$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get 

$projectid = $response1.id



$resopnse2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get 

$repoid = $resopnse2.id


echo $repoid

$urltest= "vstfs:///Git/Ref/$projectid/$repoid/GB$branchname"

echo $urltest


 $body = "[

  {
    `"op`": `"add`",
    `"path`": `"/relations/-`",
    `"value`": {
      `"rel`": `"ArtifactLink`",
      `"url`": `"$urltest`",
      `"attributes`": {
        `"name`": `"Branch`",
        `"comment`": `"test link branch`"
      }
    }
  }

   
]"


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Patch -Body $body -ContentType application/json-patch+json
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does not contain explnaition of your issue, but you can try this example with rest API through PowerShell:

```
$user = ""
$token = "<your personal access token>"
$teamProject = "<team project name>"
$orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<org name>"
$repoName = "<git repository name>"
$branchPath = "branch path" #master, dev, folder/branch_name
$wiId = "<work item id>"

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$uriUpdateWorkItem = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}"+"?api-version=6.1-preview.3"
$uriGetRepo = "$orgUrl/$teamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$repoName"+"?api-version=5.0"
$uriGetProject = "$orgUrl/_apis/projects/$teamProject"+"?api-version=5.0"

$updateBodyTemplate = "[{`"op`": `"add`",`"path`": `"/relations/-`",`"value`":{`"rel`": `"ArtifactLink`",`"url`":`"{branch_url}`", `"attributes`":{`"name`": `"Branch`"}}}]"


function InvokeGetRequest ($GetUrl)
{    
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}    
}

function InvokePatchRequest ($PostUrl, $body)
{    
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PostUrl -Method Patch -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  -Body $body
}

$repoInfo = InvokeGetRequest $uriGetRepo

$projectInfo = InvokeGetRequest $uriGetProject

$uriBranchToLink = "vstfs:///Git/Ref/" + $projectInfo.id + "/" + $repoInfo.id + "/GB$branchPath"

$wiUrl = $uriUpdateWorkItem -replace "{id}", $wiId
$updateBody = $updateBodyTemplate -replace "{branch_url}", $uriBranchToLink

$wiObj = InvokePatchRequest $wiUrl $updateBody

$wiObj
```