# Azure CLI creating a new branch from a task

Tags: git, azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli

I'm tring to automate task and branch creation on Azure boards- but am stuggling to programtically create a branch, once the task is created.
I'm using the Azure/Azure Devops extensions in PowerShell, but can't see anything in the docs that would replicate the 'create branch' link pictured below:

[image: create branch pic]

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To programmatically create a branch, here are two methods :

Az CLI : run

```
az repos ref create --name refs/heads/{branch name} --object-id {Id of the object to create the reference from} --organization https://dev.azure.com/{org name} --project {project name} --repository {repos name}
```

Rest API :

1. Get the repository ID in project setting >> your repo or use REST API [Repositories - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) and use REST API [Refs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) with `filter=<BranchName>` to get the `oldObjectId` for your specific branch:

   ```
   GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?filter=heads/master&api-version=5.1
   ```
2. Use the [Initial commit (Create a new branch)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#initial-commit-(create-a-new-branch)) to create a branch from a specific branch with the following Request Body.

> ```
> {
>   "refUpdates": [
>     {
>       "name": "refs/heads/{DefineNewBranchName}",
>       "oldObjectId": "{oldObjectId}"
>     }
>   ],
>   "commits": [
>     {
>       "comment": "Initial commit.",
>       "changes": [
>         {
>           "changeType": "add",
>           "item": {
>             "path": "/readme.md"
>           },
>           "newContent": {
>             "content": "My first file!",
>             "contentType": "rawtext"
>           }
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Next, you could link the work item with the existing Branch by using the Rest API: [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.1
```

Request Body:

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "op": "add",
>     "path": "/relations/-",
>     "value": {
>       "rel": "ArtifactLink",
>       "url": "vstfs:///Git/Ref/{ProjectID}/{RepoId}/GB{BranchName}",
>       "attributes": {
>         "name": "Branch",
>         "comment": "test link branch"
>       }
>     }
>   }
> ]
> ```

Here is a similar [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64569717/how-to-connect-a-branch-to-a-work-item-via-devops-cli-or-api) about your question.